# Reducing Valgrind memory usage for embedded target

Tags: memory, embedded, out-of-memory, valgrind, embedded-linux

I'm trying to use Valgrind to debug a crashing program on an embedded Linux target. The system has roughly 31 MB of free memory when nothing is running, and my program uses about 2 MB of memory, leaving 29 MB for Valgrind. Unfortunately, when I try to run my program under Valgrind, Valgrind reports an error:

```
Valgrind's memory management: out of memory:
   initialiseSector(TC)'s request for 27597024 bytes failed.
      50,388,992 bytes have already been mmap-ed ANONYMOUS.
Valgrind cannot continue.  Sorry.
```

Is there any way I can cut down Valgrind's memory usage so it will run successfully in this environment? Or am I just out of luck?

Comment: What caused you to want to run valgrind in the first place here?  What did the stack trace from the core dump from when your program originally tell you?

Comment: Test the code through Valgrind on a Linux desktop PC rather then trying to to squeeze it on your target.

Comment: Or use a prototype with more RAM than the production device. That's common practice.

Answer (score 2):

valgrind can be tuned to decrease (increase) its cpu/memory usage,
with an effect to decrease (increase) the information about problems/bugs.

See e.g. https://archive.fosdem.org/2015/schedule/event/valgrind_tuning/attachments/slides/743/export/events/attachments/valgrind_tuning/slides/743/tuning_V_for_your_workload.pdf

Note however that running valgrind within 31MB (or so) seems an impossible task.